# Math Question in C or Objective C

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, math

This is probably a silly and easy question, but it seems sometimes the simplest things give me more problems!

This formula is suppose to give me a number between 0 and 100.

```
(200 / 23) * Abs(Mod(2987, 23) - 23 / 2)
```

In objective C I coded it like this:

```
(200 / 23) * abs(2987 % 23) - (23 / 2);
```

Is the formula flawed (and doesn't give an answer between 0 and 100) or is my code wrong? It seems that my modulus isn't giving me the right result. Shouldn't it give me a one number integer?

Thanks

Comment: Silly question: in C this would never return a floating point number, since all values involved are integer. Does it work differently in Objective C?

Comment: Don't know what you're doing, but if you ever want a random number: `arc4random() % 100`. Either you could just write the constant number and be done with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is wrong in objective C...

```
(200 / 23) * abs(2987 % 23) - (23 / 2);
```

Should be

```
(200 / 23) * abs((2987 % 23) - (23 / 2));
```

Which is just 73.9.

But this formula is also incorrect, you want values between 0 and 100. Your current formula does not reach 0, because a%23 has a range of 0-22, so the lowest value you can get if you subtract 23/2 and then take the absolute value is .5 (11-11.5 and 12-11.5). 22 would be the ideal number in this instance.

Also by subtracting 23/2 you get an uneven distribution, if you just multiplied the mod by 100/22, you would be better off. It would help to know what you are attempting.

Comment: Indeed, he could have just written 73.9130434783 :-P.